# 'Class Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache does not exist' when installing a symfony project

Tags: php, symfony, deployment, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm trying to deploy a symfony project following the steps:

```
./composer.phar update
php bin/console cache:clear
```

I've also tried to install manually doctrine driver ArrayCache running:

```
./composer.phar require doctrine/cache
```

The results is always the same and I end up with the following error:

```
# ./composer.phar update --no-interaction
[...]
Script cache:clear returned with error code 255
!!
!!  In ContainerBuilder.php line 1089:
!!
!!    Class Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache does not exist
!!
!!
!!
Script @auto-scripts was called via post-update-cmd
```

I'm new with symfony and I'm not able to understand why this class is missing.

I'm using the following versions:

```
"symfony/framework-bundle": "5.1.*",
"doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.2",
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Try `./composer.phar install` instead

Comment: I have the same issue. I use doctrine separate, this is NOT a Symfony issue. Seems they just abandoned the caching classes. Ok, fine, but why isn't there any documentation/examples on their website? If you go to the cookbook, still all examples work with the same now abandoned cache-package! Grr....

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? As you can see on https://github.com/doctrine/cache/issues/354, the `ArrayCache` is no longer part of `doctrine/cache` v2, so you need to check which part of your application uses it. Most probably, any of the other packages you are using relies on it

Comment: @NicoHaase, as mention by 'mous' below we have opted for a doctrine version downgrade and we  will refactor code asap to use another cache solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some time, I found a better solution:

```
composer require symfony/cache
```

then in php:

```
$config = new Configuration;
$queryCache = new PhpFilesAdapter('doctrine_queries'); $config->setQueryCache($queryCache);    
$resultCache = new PhpFilesAdapter('doctrine_results', 0, $settings['cache_dir']); $config->setResultCache($resultCache);
$metaCache = new PhpFilesAdapter('doctrine_metadata', 0, $settings['cache_dir']); $config->setMetadataCache($metaCache);
```

I can now upgrade doctrine to the latest version.

This is somewhere along the line of another answer, but since the documentation is so poor (for non-Symfony user), adding a few lines of php can make all the difference!
Hope this helps some people. If this is for some reason not the best solution, I'm eager to hear.

> For me the solution is to downgrade to doctrine 2.7.4.
>
> Google'd around and it is obvious that Doctrine does not have its
> documentation in order. I'll put on my todo-list to look for another
> (3rd party) cache solution to replace the ArrayCache. I should have
> done this earlier, since ArrayCache is not suitable for production.
> Just hope Doctrine updates its documentation soon!
>
> If I find an alternative, I'll post it here. Or perhaps someone else
> beats me to it, I hope so!

Comment: Thank for your reply, we have opted for the same solution, for now we have fixed the version to doctrine 2.7.4 in composer. We are waiting for code refactoring allowing us to use another cache driver.

Obviously, there is a lack of documentation from both Symfony and Doctrine about this deprecation. Wait and see for some update on this point.

Comment: what do you mean when you write "in php:", where in the symfony project, in which file?

Comment: I'm not using symfony.

Answer (score 10):

I think you installed `doctrine/cache` 2.x version when installed `"doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.2",`.

From [github page](https://github.com/doctrine/cache/tree/2.0.x):

`This library is deprecated and will no longer receive bug fixes from the Doctrine Project. Please use a different cache library, preferably PSR-6 or PSR-16 instead.`

So you have next options:

- `composer require doctrine/cache:^1.11`
- To use other lib for cache for example [symfony/cache](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/cache.html)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's established in the other answers that somewhere you are instantiating an instance of `ArrayCache` from the **doctrine/cache** package.

If you want equivalent functionality with **doctrine/cache** 2.x (where `ArrayCache` has been removed) you can do what **doctrine/dbal** itself will do.

I.e. instead of this...

```php
$cache = new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache();
```

... you may instead do this (assuming you are comfortable introducing the **symfony/cache** package) ...

```php
$cache = \Doctrine\Common\Cache\Psr6\DoctrineProvider::wrap(
    new \Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\ArrayAdapter()
)
```

This is what Doctrine itself does as a fallback when `ArrayCache` does not exists and you do not otherwise specify a cache in dev-mode. You can see the logic for how Doctrine decides to instantiate a cache at `\Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup::createCacheInstance`.

*(Note: Even when you do not specify a cache, Doctrine will instantiate one automatically -- it could be storing values in Redis without you even realising )*

Answer (score -2):

To solve this problem, i first **delete the composer.lock file**, after, i installed composer with this following command: **composer install** and I installed the symfony cache dependency with this following command: composer **require symfony/cach**

->https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/cache

Comment: Removing `composer.lock`  is never a good iead. Why not install any package without removing all other resolved dependencies?

Comment: For a real answer, you should indicate how this actually solves the problem. Provide us with some code how you initialize the cache, etc.