# composer install/update trigger Class Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache does not exist

Tags: symfony, doctrine, composer-php

I'm using symfony5 and wanted to deploy earlier today, which failed with the following error on vendor loading with `composer install` or `composer update` :

[image]

according to this issue ['Class Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache does not exist' when installing a symfony project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68166221/class-doctrine-common-cache-arraycache-does-not-exist-when-installing-a-symfon/68651823?noredirect=1#comment121326359_68651823) which worked for some the error might come from my doctrine version but as i have not updated it in the past few days I do not understand how it could

Here is my `composer.json` in case:

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.4",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "ext-json": "*",
        "ext-zip": "*",
        "api-platform/core": "^2.5",
        "beberlei/doctrineextensions": "^1.3",
        "composer/package-versions-deprecated": "^1.11",
        "digitick/sepa-xml": "^2.1",
        "doctrine/annotations": "^1.0",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.1",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.0",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.7",
        "gesdinet/jwt-refresh-token-bundle": "^0.9.1",
        "giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php": "^8.12",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0",
        "h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64": "^0.12.4",
        "jsor/doctrine-postgis": "^1.7",
        "knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle": "^1.8",
        "lcobucci/jwt": "^3.3",
        "lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle": "^2.8",
        "nelmio/cors-bundle": "^2.1",
        "phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock": "^5.2",
        "ramsey/uuid": "^4.1",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.6",
        "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "^1.5",
        "stripe/stripe-php": "^7.62",
        "symfony/amqp-messenger": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/asset": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/console": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/dependency-injection": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/expression-language": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.3.1",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/http-client": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/mailer": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/mercure-bundle": "^0.2.5",
        "symfony/messenger": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.6",
        "symfony/property-access": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/property-info": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/serializer": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/translation": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/validator": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/yaml": "5.1.*",
        "twig/cssinliner-extra": "^3.1",
        "twig/extra-bundle": "^2.12|^3.0",
        "twig/inky-extra": "^3.1",
        "twig/twig": "^2.12|^3.0",
        "twilio/sdk": "^6.16",
        "vich/uploader-bundle": "^1.16"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "api-platform/schema-generator": "^2.2",
        "dama/doctrine-test-bundle": "^6.4",
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "^3.3",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.9",
        "justinrainbow/json-schema": "^5.2",
        "symfony/browser-kit": "^5.1",
        "symfony/css-selector": "^5.1",
        "symfony/debug-bundle": "^5.1",
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.21",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^5.1",
        "symfony/stopwatch": "^5.1",
        "symfony/var-dumper": "^5.1",
        "symfony/web-profiler-bundle": "^5.1"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "paragonie/random_compat": "2.*",
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php74": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php73": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php72": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php71": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php70": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php56": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "5.1.*"
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know where this error could come from or can think of possbile leads about possible resolution as I am stuck on this problem

Thank you

### Update

result of `composer install -v`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I've updated w my full `composer.json`
I've also tried the two other solutions which resulted to the same error as in my post

Comment: I've updated my post with the result of `composer install -v` and I'm running the dev environment

Comment: Okay I've deleted `var/cache/dev` and reinstalled but still have the same result

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? What has changed since the last working version? Maybe there **has** been an update of any package, as that `ArrayCache` has been removed in `doctrine/cache` v2?

Comment: The issue is caused by `api-platform/core: ^2.5` not being compatible with `doctrine/cache: ^2.0` This can be confirmed by calling `composer remove api-platform/core`. You need to require `api-platform/core: ^2.6` with Symfony 5.2 or require `doctrine/cache: ^1.12`

Comment: The issue appears to stem from `symfony/framework-bundle: 5.1.11` [service declaration for `annotations.cached_reader`](https://github.com/symfony/framework-bundle/blob/v5.1.11/Resources/config/annotations.xml#L24) using `ArrayCache` being changed in [4.4.20 and 5.2.4 to `ArrayAdapter`](https://github.com/symfony/framework-bundle/blob/v5.2.4/Resources/config/annotations.php#L38). Which does not appear to have been ported over to the 5.1 branch. Changing def manually resolves the issue. See [commit](https://github.com/symfony/framework-bundle/commit/62ec87801c00324acc819b8022f204ccc88f8316).

Comment: @WillB. Symfony 5.1 is no longer maintained - the support has ended in January 2021, while this change has happened some months later

Comment: @NicoHaase correct. For some reason when api-platform/core is required in Symfony 5.1 it causes the exception to be thrown. But remove api-platform or changing the service definition manually in symfony/framework-bundle 5.1 and api-platform/core the issue no longer persists. Still trying to determine why. None-the-less it appears Symfony 5.1 is not compatible with `doctrine/cache >= 2.0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can read in an [issue posted in the issue tracker](https://github.com/doctrine/cache/issues/354) of `doctrine/cache`, that class has been deprecated in v1 of that package, and removed in v2.

If you still want to use that class, run `composer require doctrine/cache "^1.12"` to install a version of that package from the v1 branch.

---

On the long run, you should check where your application requires that class and search for alternatives. If you need help with that, please share more details.

Comment: This is by far the easiest solution to ensure compatibility with Symfony 5.1 as it is no longer supported and `symfony/framework-bundle` uses `Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache` as a [service definition](https://github.com/symfony/framework-bundle/blob/v5.1.11/Resources/config/annotations.xml#L27).